# Using sqlalchemy with flaskmysql : error Sqlalchemy engine=None

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
```

i have set
`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://~'`

`db.init_app(app) migrate.init_app(app,db)`

when i print db
i get

anyone could please tell me how to give uri to sqlalchemy engine?
i tried create_engine with that uri and checked it was working..

Comment: when i print 'db' i get '''<SQLAlchemy engine=None>'''

Comment: The URI looks wrong, I would expect it t look like `mysql+mysqldb://username:password@host:port/databasename`

Comment: No... that uri worked on using create_engine(uri). So uri is fine..